# Regex that only matches words containing a defined set of characters

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that only matches words that use a certain set of letters.

For instance if my set of letters is ['b', 'o', 'n', 'd'] and the words I am checking are 'bob', 'baboon', 'bond', 'bonded' and 'racket', then the regular expression should match 'bob' and 'bond' and reject everything else. The word doesn't have to contain all the words in the set, but it can't include letters that are not in the set.

Any Help?

Comment: have you tried any regex and didn't work ?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Here we answer specific questions when you get stuck, having done your research and tried something (ie. show your working so far).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  (^[bond]+$)
```

This should do it.You can add other characters if you want.

For exactlyy 2 b's you can add a lookahead.

```
(?=^[ond]*b[ond]*b[ond]*$)(^[bond]+$)
```

Comment: That's worked great, Thanks. Is there anyway for me to specify that a certain character should only be included a specified amount of times. For instance how could I say that I only want 2 'b' and 1 'o' to be in the word?

Comment: @RorySimpson Try this new one.